# Why is vsprintf only operating on the first character

Tags: c

The code below returns the following:

```
Input was: 6789
Vsprintf Buffer: 54
```

Why is the `vsprintf` buffer only returning 54?

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void vout(char *string, char *fmt, ...);
char fmt1 [] = "%d";

int main(void)
{
   char string[32];
   char *xy = "6789";

   vout(string, fmt1, * xy);
   printf("Input was: %s\n", xy);
   printf("Vsprintf Buffer:  %s\n",string);
}

void vout(char *string, char *fmt, ...)
{
   va_list arg_ptr;

   va_start(arg_ptr, fmt);
   vsprintf(string, fmt, arg_ptr);
   va_end(arg_ptr);
}
```

Comment: Because 54 is the ASCII code for `'6'`.

Comment: But... that's exactly and explicitly what you are doing in your code: passing only the first character of `xy` to `vout` and converting its integer value to string. `*xy` is the first character of `xy`. You deliberately singled it out yourself, right there. Why the question then?

Comment: If you don't like the result, please **always** include what your expected result is.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a single character `'6'` and printing it with the format`%d`, so it prints the character code as an integer -- `54`.

Answer (score 0):

vsprintf() reads fmt from arg_ptr and prints to string. This will not work, as it will take the first 32-bit memory block, in this case, containing the ascii character '6', and write it as an integer to string. Use vsscanf instead.

```
vsscanf(string, fmt, arg_ptr);
```

Comment: And also, an easy way to remember the order of the arguments of vsscanf and vsprintf is that the arguments are basically the same as scanf and printf, just with a character array before the arguments, that is read from/written to instead of stdin.